# Calculating array number inputs in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, calculator

So this is how far I've gone with the code. Everything works OK yet I have not a clue how to proceed further. What I need to do right now is to do the calculation process and have it printed in the text field. I had the idea of having the math part in view controller class and working with string numbers, but I wanted to see if you can work with numbers in arrays.

This is the class for the operation:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class Calculation {

    var operation: String = ""
    var numbers: [Int] = []


    func operationInput() {

        switch operation {    // I still haven't figured out how to write the math part of it with array numbers.
        case "+":
            break
        case "-":
            break
        case "*":
            break
        case "/":
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my main view controller:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
    var numbers: String = ""
    var calculation = Calculation()
    var finalNumber: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func acPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        resultLabel.text = "0"
        numbers = ""
    }

    @IBAction func numberPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let number = sender.titleLabel?.text
        numbers.append(number!)
        print(numbers)
        resultLabel.text = numbers

    }

    @IBAction func operationPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let operationInput = sender.title(for: .normal)!
        calculation.numbers.append(Int(numbers)!)
        print(operationInput)
        print(calculation.numbers[0])
        numbers = ""
        resultLabel.text = calculation.operation
    }

    @IBAction func equationOperator(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let equation = sender.title(for: .normal)!
        if equation == "=" {
            finalNumber = Int(numbers)!
            resultLabel.text = "\(finalNumber)"
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you can just use 2 different variables to make things simpler and 3rd one to store result in